# Can't open hprof file after my JVM crash whether hprof file will be created correctly at time of JVM crash?

Tags: java

In the error log, I am getting:

```
Eden space 699392K, 99% used. 
Event: 35492.555 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1649 (full 228):
```

And after GC run also same result. It was full since my server generated the hprof file but I am not able to open it in any of the tools, so my doubt is at the time of JVM crashed whether hprof file has being created correctly or not.

Comment: There is no guarantee, but if you have configured the JVM to generate a dump file on out of memory and there is a dump file there which is not empty and you have sufficient space on your disks I would think that the file is valid. It usually is.

Comment: In my case out of memory i am hving doubt because when I check my server logs load was very less.
  Previously for out of memory error(Load used to be more), i used to get proper hprof file having good size
  for analysis. But for this issue 
  In my error log  i am getting : {Heap before GC invocations=1649 (full 228):
  PSYoungGen      total 1398272K, used 699392K
  eden space 699392K, 100% used  and i want to know for which class object memory got leaked 
  for that reason i hprof i was checking but it is showing corrupted.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "crash".   If it was a JVM panic / hard crash, then all bets are off.

Comment: Its look like a hard crash below is the error. #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fef9fbb203b, pid=13923, tid=0x00007fef83dfd700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b31) (build 1.8.0_131-b31)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b31 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x69403b]  java_lang_Class::signers(oopDesc*)+0x1b
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try

Comment: If the JVM hard crashes, it is likely that the hprof file won't be written fully.

Comment: I got the HPROF file which is having very less size(Compare to what earlier I used to get when out of memory used to happen) and while analyzing it with Memory Analyzer Tool it is throwing EOF  exception and with an online tool, it was showing file is corrupted. So is it because of HPROF file not written fully or can you suggest some good tool to analyze?